# Closed form expression for sum of exponentials $\sum_n e^{-\alpha n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Is there a closed form expression for the following sum
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{-\alpha n } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
with $\alpha >0$ and possibly $N \to \infty$?

Comment: For $N \to \infty,$ Li$_{1/2}(e^{-\alpha})$ where Li$_s(x)$ is the polylogarithm.  Although it seems more like a definition, there are functional equations, integral representations, etc. that can prove useful for a particular application, so I'd begin by researching the polylogarithm.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. That is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: For the finite case, it's doubtful there is a closed form expression for this sum.

Comment: There apparently is a [closed form in terms of the Lerch Transcendent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+e%5E%28-an%29%2Fsqrt%28n%29), but I am not sure how to derive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no closed form in terms of elementary functions. However, according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5EN+e%5E%28-a*n%29%2Fsqrt%28n%29), we have the following expression in the finite case:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{-\alpha n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{-\alpha})-e^{-\alpha(N+1)}\Phi(e^{-\alpha},1/2,N+1),$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_s(x)$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^s},$$
and $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is the [Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)
$$\Phi(z,s,a):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+\alpha)^s}.$$

---

To derive this result, note that
$$\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{-\alpha n}}{\sqrt{n}}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha n}}{\sqrt{n}}-\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha n}}{\sqrt{n}}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-\alpha})^n}{n^{1/2}}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha (k+N+1)}}{\sqrt{k+N+1}}\\&=\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{-\alpha})-e^{-\alpha (N+1)} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-\alpha})^k}{(k+(N+1))^{1/2}}\\&=\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{-\alpha})-e^{-\alpha(N+1)}\Phi(e^{-\alpha},1/2,N+1),\end{align}$$
where we have used the change of dummy index $k=n-(N+1)$ when going from the first to the second line. In the limit $N\to \infty$, we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{-\alpha}).$$